# ¿Cómo acceder al cuerpo de una petición PUT con PHP?

Tags: php, postman

Estoy estudiando un poco de API's y para ello estoy usando POSTMAN. Resulta que con el metodo POST agregué datos a una tabla mysql.

| id | nombres | imagen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Juan | nombre-imagen.jpg |

Nada complicado; en una de ellas tengo el campo de img donde guardo la imagen en una carpeta mientras que en la DB guarda su nombre para posteriormente mostrarlo.

Hasta ahí todo bien. Ahora mi duda es ¿cómo se haría para editar la imagen al usar el método PUT? Pasa que intento actualizar por body pero no consigo capturar los datos enviados vía postman.

| key | value | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| img | nueva-img.jpg |  |

Este es el código que estoy usando para el método PUT:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {

  if (isset($_POST['img'])) {
  echo $_POST['img'];
 //no muestra nada al hacer echo

}

}
```

Quise intentar haciendo un GET con params y usando el mismo PUT en postman pero tampoco consigo enviar los datos de la imagen ya que por parámetros no permite enviar imágenes. ¿Cómo podría solucionar esto?

Comment: La [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.put-method.php) dice algo al respecto.

Answer (score 0):

Para acceder a los datos puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
$metodo = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

if($metodo == "PUT") {
  $datos = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
  var_dump($datos);  
}
```

Comment: lo voy a probar gracias